# PowerBi User Friendly way to filter rows by date across multiple tables easily

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to set a variable in one place such as the date you want to filter data by before import and apply that variable to all tables?

As is, I need to manually change the filter across several tables which is time consuming and not friendly to users not used to database management.

Comment: This is what a calendar table (or [date dimension table](https://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension)) is typically used for.

Comment: No its not. A calendar table is for visualizations and slicing, not for filtering at the source BEFORE importing

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed "before import" on my first read. It sounds like a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters) is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a date [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters) to use in all your relevant queries.

For example, instead of filtering for `[Date] > #date(2020,12,31)`, youd write `[Date] > DateParameter` and set that parameter separately.